# LibGit2Sharp 1 conflict prevent from checkout

Tags: c#, .net, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I currently have the problem, that my application using libgit2sharp always crashs witht the message:

> 1 conflict prevents from checkout

when trying to call `repo.Pull`

The curious thing is, if i print the status of the local repository, their are no changes in the repository.

I even tried resetting the repository at first, or checking the files out, but nothing helps. This is my code:

```
using (LibGit2Sharp.Repository repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(path))
{
    var tipId = repo.Head.Tip.Tree;
    Log.LogManagerInstance.Instance.Info("HEAD tree id: " + tipId.Id.ToString());

    // Pull changes
    PullOptions options = new PullOptions();

    options.FetchOptions = new FetchOptions();
    options.MergeOptions = new MergeOptions();

    // ! Only for trying to fix the bug. Should not be here
    options.MergeOptions.FileConflictStrategy = CheckoutFileConflictStrategy.Theirs;

    repo.Reset(repo.Head.Tip);
    // ! --

    options.FetchOptions.CredentialsProvider = CredentialsHandler;

    Log.LogManagerInstance.Instance.Info("Try pull from remote repository");

    // Pull changes from network
    var result = repo.Network.Pull(new LibGit2Sharp.Signature(username, mail, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)), options);

    if (result != null && result.Commit != null)
    {
        Log.LogManagerInstance.Instance.Info("Pulled from remote branch, new tree id: " + result.Commit.Tree.Id.ToString());

        // get difference in the git tree (file-system)
        var diffs = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(tipId, result.Commit.Tree);

        MergeTreeChangesToDatabase(diffs, path);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.LogManagerInstance.Instance.Info("Local repository is up-to-date with the remote branch");
    }
}
```

### Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

> Using the pre release `0.22` seems to solve my problem.

Comment: What version of LibGit2Sharp are you using? Where do you see this message? is this the exception message? If you pull from the command line, does it succeed? One possible issue is that you have a local untracked (or git ignored) file that would be overwritten by the commits you are pulling down.

Comment: I am using `0.21.0.176`. The message is an exception in an console application. Yes, if i pull from the command line with git bash, every thing works just fine.

Comment: I also don't have any git ignored or untracked file. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Version 0.22 fix all problems.